# Processing arguments from file/cli/stdin in bash

Tags: bash, shell, cron, config

I can see myself ending up writing a lot of scripts which do some thing based on some arguments on the command line.

This then progresses to doing more or less the same thing multiple times automated with a scheduler.

To prevent myself having to create a new job for each variation on the arguments, I would like to create a simple script skeleton which I can use to quickly create scripts which take the same arguments from:

- The command line
- A file from a path specified on the command line
- From stdin until eof

My initial approach for taking arguments or config from a TAB delim file was as follows:

```
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "Using config file '$1'"
    IFS='   '
    cat $1 | grep -v "^#" | while read line; do
            if [ "$line" != "" ]; then
                    echo $line
                    #call fn with line as args
            fi
    done
    unset IFS
elif [ -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "Using cli arguments..."
    #call fn with $1 $2 $3 etc...
else
    echo "Read from stdin, ^d will terminate"
    IFS='   '
    while read line; do
            if [ "$(echo $line | grep -v "^#")" != "" ]; then
                    #call fn with line as args
            fi
    done
    unset IFS
fi
```

So to all those who have doubtless done this kind of thing before:

1. How did/would you go about it?
2. Am I being too procedural - could this be better done with awk or similar?
3. Is this the best approach anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure whether I'm a bit wide of the mark, but it sounds like you are trying to reinvent xargs.

If you have a script, normally invoked as such

```
$ your_script.sh -d foo bar baz
```

You can get the parameters from stdin as follows:

```
$ xargs your_script.sh
-d foo
bar
baz
^D
```

Our from a file

```
$ cat config_file | xargs your_script.sh
```

(assuming that config_file has the following content)

```
-d foo bar 
baz
```

Or from multiple config files

```
$ cat config_file1 config_file2 | xargs your_script.sh
```

Comment: This sounds like how it should be done, with scripts designed to work well with these cases in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can you think of a standard Unix utility that behaves as you describe?  (No, I can't.)  That suggests that you are slightly off-target with your goal.

The testing of `-f "$1"` and `-d "$1"` is not conventional, but if your script only works on directories, maybe it makes sense.

Ultimately, I think you need an interface like:

```
your_cmd [-f argumentlist] [file ...]
```

The explicit but optional `-f argumentlist` allows you to specify the file to read from on the command line.  Otherwise, the files specified on the command line are processed, unless there are no such arguments, in which case the file names to be processed are read from standard input.  This is a lot closer to a conventional organization.  We can debate about the handling of file names with spaces and newlines in the names some other time.

The core of your code will be written to accept/process one file name at a time.  This might be written as a shell function, which allows the maximum reuse.

```
while getopts f: opt
do
    case $opt in
    (f) while read file; do shell_function $file; done < $OPTARG; exit 0;;
    (*) : Error handling etc;;
    esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
case $# in
(0) while read file; do shell_function $file; done; exit 0;;
(*) for file in "$@"; do shell_function $file; done; exit 0;;
esac
```

It is not very hard to ring the variations on this.  It is also tolerably compact.

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers, +1, and thanks a lot for the example - very interesting.